# Periodic task in Qt without interrupting events

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwidget

I have a graphic application in python using `QWidget`. The user can change elements by moving the mouse (using `mouseMoveEvent`), and the program should periodically (e.g., once per second) compute a function `update_forces` based on these elements.

**Problem:** the `mouseMoveEvent` doesn't trigger as often while `update_forces` is computed, so the program becomes periodically unresponsive. There are various tutorials online on how to remedy this using threads, but their solutions don't work for me, and I don't know why.

## MWE

```
# Imports
import sys
import random
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication

# update_forces dummy
def update_forces():
    for i in range(10000000):
        x = i**2

# Worker object:
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    def run(self):
        while(True):
            update_forces()
            time.sleep(1)

# and the Window class with a dummy mouseEvent that just prints a random number
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(20, 20, 500, 500)
        self.show()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        print(random.random())

# head procedure
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run this (Windows 10) and move my cursor around on the screen, I can clearly observe two phases: it goes from printing numbers rapidly (while `update_forces` is not computed), to printing them much more slowly (while it is computed). It keeps alternating between both.

Comment: 1. Please put code belonging to the same file in a single block, don't split it to tell what it does, it's just distracting and annoying to read (use code comments, *if* necessary); 2. The loop takes complete control, treading (most importantly, Python threading) does not allow full concurrency, especially if it's completely CPU wise. If that function is that demanding, then you need to find a way to occasionally release control (even a simple `time.sleep(0)`) to the other thread.

Comment: 1. Done 2. That would explain it, but adding `if i%10000 == 0: time.sleep(0)` to the MWE (in `update_forces`) does not solve the issue. And yeah, the function really is that demanding.

Comment: That may depend on the system (CPU and/or OS), consider that on Linux I cannot reproduce the issue of your example (I cannot try on other systems now). AFAIK it should work on Windows (since it uses Sleep(0)); try with a slightly bigger interval, like `0.001`. In any case, you could consider multiprocessing, but be aware that using it with Qt isn't immediate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use multiprocessing rather than threading.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=updater, args=())
    p.start()

def updater(queue,test):
    while(True):
        update_forces()
        time.sleep(1)
```

The problem with this is that no data is shared between processes by default, but that's solvable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ... ... bad bot.